# Cannot reduce height of image in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie to web development. I wanted to reduce the size of an image, but the height of the image is not being reduced. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style="width: 100%; height: 30%" src="images/test.jpg" alt="test image">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also make use of min-height

Comment: Do you want to keep the aspect ratio of the image? Or do you just want to reduce its height even if the image might be distorted?

Comment: Ideally, I would like the image to fit the body of the browser window. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `height` instead of `max-height`. `max-height` only specifies the maximum height an element can take and not the actual height.

Also, since you are using percentage to define `height`, make sure that the parent element(in your case, `body`) is given a `height`.

Comment: It doesn't work with height either. And what do you mean parement element being height. Can you give example code?

Comment: set the height of body tag to some pixel value, say 300px, then you'll understand.

Comment: I see. It works indeed now. Can I also make the image fit the browser window exactly automatically?

Comment: set body tag's height to `100vh`. Although, it won't work in some older browsers.

Comment: I see. Cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [img-tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) has not property max-height and max-width!
You need [width](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp) and [height](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_height.asp)

You can try this on [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_height)

Answer (score 2):

you are providing the max-width and max-height in percentage, so it need a container in whose respect it will set the height

```
<div style="height: 100px" >
<img src="http://i1.wp.com/static.web-backgrounds.net/uploads/2012/08/City_Landscape_Background.jpg"  style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 50%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="height:30%;width:100%"` or define height and width to an outer parent.

Answer (score 1):

The parent element height can also be given in percentages.
But,It should be given.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My test page</title>
<style>
html{
height:100%;
}
body{
height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img style="width: 100%; height: 30%" src="images/test.jpg" alt="test image">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the image into a `<div>` tag and then use height/width or Max/Min-Width/Height to alter the height using percentages.

Answer (score 0):

If you define width, let height auto, or the other way around, to respect ratio.

Here's what Bootstrap does for responsive images

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You can then constraint the container.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljn7qm22/1/

Note that for performance, you should not resize images (letting browser load a big image, and only showing a little thing to the user).